# Constant error in Hibernate Template update hql

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

My client class uses the updateCustomer method in CustomerService class:

```
    Customer updatedCustomer = new Customer("2314DD0", "POJO World", "Offers POJO service.");
    customerService.updateCustomer(updatedCustomer);
```

I've tried all sorts of things to work around "updateOrSave", different arguments for update, and so on. The problem that I am encountering according to the stack trace is a (HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException) and a (org.hibernate.StaleStateException). But let me explain first: All my other data accesses (i.e. save, delete, and query) work perfectly well. I am suspicious about my customer domain class, as well as the Customer.hbm.xml that I've set up.

So, my Customer Service class:

```
public void updateCustomer(Customer updatedCustomer) 
{
    this.dao.update(updatedCustomer);
}
```

Customer Service Dao:

```
public void update(Customer customerToUpdate)
{
    template.update("Customer", customerToUpdate);
}
```

domain.Customer class:

```
public class Customer 
{
private int id; 
private String customerId, companyName, email, telephone, notes;

private Customer() {}

public Customer(String customerId, String companyName, String email,
                String telephone, String notes)
{
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.email = email;
    this.telephone = telephone;
    this.notes = notes;
}

//Getters and Setters for ALL instance variables listed after this point. 
}
```

Finally, my Customer.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" 
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.crm.domain.Customer">

   <id name="id" column="ID">
      <generator class="native"/>
   </id>

   <property name="customerId"/>
   <property name="companyName"/>
   <property name="email"/>
   <property name="telephone"/>
   <property name="notes"/>
</class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a new object, which is implied by `new Customer("2314DD0", "POJO World", "Offers POJO service.");` then shouldn't you be calling `save()` or `persist()` instead of `update()`?

Comment: What I am trying to do is to update an existing customer with customerId of "2314DD0". What I've done is replace one of the customer's parameters with "POJO World". So the updated customer would have the "new Customer"'s attributes, while the customerId and so forth are the same. This is why I believed that "update" would be more appropriate.

Comment: if you want to update, you should probably load the object from the database by id, then make the changes, then update.